# How to blur image using glsl shader without squares?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, blur, gpuimage

I want to blur image with Gaussian blur algorithm. And I use the following shaders:

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

const int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;

uniform float texelWidthOffset;
uniform float texelHeightOffset;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;

    // Calculate the positions for the blur
    int multiplier = 0;
    vec2 blurStep;
   vec2 singleStepOffset = vec2(texelHeightOffset, texelWidthOffset);

    for (int i = 0; i < GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES; i++)
   {
        multiplier = (i - ((GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES - 1) / 2));
       // Blur in x (horizontal)
       blurStep = float(multiplier) * singleStepOffset;
        blurCoordinates[i] = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + blurStep;
    }
}
```

Fragment shader

```
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

const lowp int GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES = 9;

varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
varying highp vec2 blurCoordinates[GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES];

void main()
{
    lowp vec3 sum = vec3(0.0);
   lowp vec4 fragColor=texture2D(inputImageTexture,textureCoordinate);

    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[0]).rgb * 0.05;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[1]).rgb * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[2]).rgb * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[3]).rgb * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[4]).rgb * 0.18;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[5]).rgb * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[6]).rgb * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[7]).rgb * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(inputImageTexture, blurCoordinates[8]).rgb * 0.05;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(sum,fragColor.a);
}
```

I use this code to load and compile shaders

```
public static int loadShader(final String strSource, final int iType) {
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        int iShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(iType);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(iShader, strSource);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(iShader);
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(iShader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.d("Load Shader Failed", "Compilation\n" + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(iShader));
            return 0;
        }
        return iShader;
    }

    public static int loadProgram(final String strVSource, final String strFSource) {
        int iVShader;
        int iFShader;
        int iProgId;
        int[] link = new int[1];
        iVShader = loadShader(strVSource, GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        if (iVShader == 0) {
            Log.d("Load Program", "Vertex Shader Failed");
            return 0;
        }
        iFShader = loadShader(strFSource, GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (iFShader == 0) {
            Log.d("Load Program", "Fragment Shader Failed");
            return 0;
        }

        iProgId = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(iProgId, iVShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(iProgId, iFShader);

        GLES20.glLinkProgram(iProgId);

        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(iProgId, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, link, 0);
        if (link[0] <= 0) {
            Log.d("Load Program", "Linking Failed");
            return 0;
        }
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(iVShader);
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(iFShader);
        return iProgId;
    }
```

This produces an image with a lot of blurred squares.

[image]

But. How to get something like this?

[image]

Comment: Does the same problem happen when you calculate the blurCoordinates in the fragment shader?

Comment: I compile and run both shaders: fragment and vertex

Comment: vec2(texelHeightOffset, texelWidthOffset); is inverted, causing the blur kernel to be wrong

Comment: What texture filtering did you use? I assume you need to use GL_NEAREST. Also sum of coefficients should be 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
vec2(texelHeightOffset, texelWidthOffset);
```

is inverted, causing the blur kernel to be wrong.

change it to:

```
vec2(texelWidthOffset, texelHeightOffset);
```

Also you're making a diagonal blur ranging in +-(size/2)*pixelSize,
to complete the smooth blur you want, you have to make a square kernel:

```
kernHSize = (sqrt(GAUSSIAN_SAMPLES)-1)/2;
for(y=-kernHSize; y<kernHSize; y++)
    for(x=-kernHSize; x<kernHSize; x++)
        blurCoordinates[y*kernHSize+x] = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + vec2(x*texelWidthOffset,y*texelHeightOffset);
```

then, the correct kernel coef could be:

```
{1/16,1/8,1/16,1/8,1/4,1/8,1/16,1/8,1/16}
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Changing this line produces very strange results

Comment: @SemGnil: don't know if you could get better result with diagonal blur, try square one.

Comment: Gaussion blur is a separable filter, so blurring once in x and then the result in y direction should do the trick.

Comment: There is a limitation on blurCoordinates size in GLSL. It's 16. How can I pass all the results?

Comment: You may hardcode texel sampling offset with https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/textureOffset.xhtml, and pass only center texCoord to fragShader