# Three.js. Gaussian blur for flying plates

Tags: reactjs, three.js, blur, gaussian

I have canvas-three.js background scene. There is some flying plates with image. I have to blur all plates if they are moving behind the div.  How to do this?

Comment: Here's a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625986/three-js-gaussian-blur-in-glsl-shader But that question has no answer yet.

Comment: Here's another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778381/how-to-blur-image-using-glsl-shader-without-squares